# C# - Unit Test for Json Data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, unit-testing

Please how can I write a Unit Test for crud api returning Json

```
    //Get all cli
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetAllCli()
    {
      var data = db.cli.ToList();
      return Json(data);
    }


        // Post method for GetAllCli
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post()
    {
           var pu = new client
            {
                FirstName = first,
                LastName = last,
                Address = addre,
            };
            db.cli.Add(pu);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new { StatusCode = "Success" });
    }
```

Wasn't sure of how to go forward with this

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetAll_ShouldReturnAllCli()
    {
        var contrller = new CliController();

        var result = contrller.GetAllCli() as JsonResult;
        //result is null after this line
        //Is there a way to get result count of the json dat

        Assert.AreEqual(5, result);
    }
```

result is always null. 
Is there a way to get the count result of the json dat

Comment: Can you please describe in more detail what you tried and where you encountered problems?

Comment: added test method

Comment: @NiangMoore Include the definition of the `GetAllCli` action, not just the body of the action.

Comment: @NiangMoore Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that clarifies your specific problem or additional details to highlight exactly what was done, it will be difficult to reproduce the problem that would allow a better understanding of what is the *actual* problem. That first snippet is unclear.

Comment: @NiangMoore where does `db` come from? If we can't see the code there is not much help that can be provided.

Answer (score 0):

In `Web API` `Json` method returns generic `JsonResult<T>` (from `System.Web.Http.Results`) and not `JsonResult` (from `System.Web.Mvc`) that's why you get `null` during cast. In order to cast to generic type you should **not** use anonymous type but define a class for result

```
public class Result
{
    public string StatusCode { get; set; }
}
```

Then your test will look like this

```
using System.Web.Http.Results;
//...

var contrller = new CliController();
var result = contrller.GetAllCli() as JsonResult<Result>;
```

Comment: result still returns null

Comment: @NiangMoore Did you change this line `return Json(new { StatusCode = "Success" });` to `return Json(new Result { StatusCode = "Success" });`?

Answer (score -1):

Update your test method as below, if you are only stuck at getting a count add more description in your question to make it clear what you have and what you are trying to do

```
[TestMethod]
    public void GetAll_ShouldReturnAllCli()
    {
        var contrller = new CliController();

        var result = contrller.GetAllCli() as JsonResult;
        var Originalresult = JsonHelper.GetJsonObjectRepresentation<IDictionary<string, object>>(result);


        Assert.AreEqual(5, Originalresult.count());
    }
```

Comment: This returns null

             var result = contrller.GetAllCli() as JsonResult;

Comment: do you get data in your controller if called from the browser?